# How may I change particular list element type into another in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make my first app which will be speech recogniser with calculation functions. Currently I have problem. I have prepared my program to add words as a list and choose first and third words as numbers and second as operator. My problem is that result is a string not int so if I for example add 20 + 40 result will be 2040 which is obviously String. I have tried to change whole list into Integers but it is impossible since my operator is not Integer. I cannot use isnumeric() or isdigit() since it is a list.
Any ideas how to proceed?

PS: My main learning language is java but for purposes of this app I have found python easier to learn and make an app this way. I know that in Java I could use:

```
int number1 = stringToNumber.conver(array[0]);
```

Unfortunately I do not know if there is similar method in python.
Thanks

Comment: I posted an answer below. If it still doesn't answer your question, please post your python code to show what you have so far. Also tell us what errors you get when you run the code.

Comment: Please check code, I have edited original post

Comment: Instead of looping over the list with `for str in words` you should check `if words[1] in addition` directly. Otherwise if the user happened to make a list like `['plus', '1', '2']`, your loop will try to convert `'plus'` to an integer which will crash.

Comment: Requiring the sentence to use the format `number operator number` makes the coding much easier. Once you figure out how to do it with that restriction, then you can work on relaxing the restriction to be more flexible in the structure of the input.

Comment: -Code-Apprentice thank you very much for your suggestions. I will definately try to implement it to improve my methods. Kinda weird to prepare my first app on my own so any suggestions I will gladly take. It is also very exciting for me :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use int()

```
list = ["20", "+", "40"]
num1 = int(list[0])
num2 = int(list[2])
op = list[1]

if op == '+':
    print(num1+num2)
elif op == '-':
    print(num1-num2)
# any other ops
```

Comment: Please check code, I have edited original post

Comment: I saw the edit and I think it has something to do with the input that you are passing. The code definitely works, see here (I replaced a few things): https://ideone.com/jvKJ0x Can you print the `text` and see if it's what you expect? Are you using `result` as a `string` somewhere in your code after this? (It is an `int`) Let me know if you can't get it to work. Try to spot the line number which causes the error.

Comment: You are right. If I will print out the result is correct but somehow my voice function does not support voice result. I will figure it out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

While you can convert the numeric string to int in the list, I suggest doing it when you perform the operation instead. For example:

```
result = int(array[0]) + int(array[2])
```